# Include regex elements in BSONArrayBuilder

Tags: c++, regex, mongodb, bson

The [BSONArrayBuilder class](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_array_builder.html) in the MongoDB C++ driver API allows to build BSON arrays, eg.

```
BSONArrayBuilder ba;
ba.append("foo");
ba.append("bar");
...
connection->query("col", BSON("x" << BSON("$in" << ba.arr())));
```

will do a query equal to the following at mongo shell:

```
db.col.find({"x": {"$in": [ "foo", "bar" ] }})
```

However, I need to do a query based on regex instead of strings, in the following way (that works at mongo shell):

```
db.col.find({"x": {"$in": [ /^foo/, /^bar/ ] }})
```

How can I build that array using the C++ driver? Note that [BSONObjBuilder class](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj_builder.html) has an `appendRegex()` method which is not included in the BSONArrayBuilder class

Any workaround or pointer to information about this problems is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The lack of answers may mean that it is not possible to do that with the current driver C++ implementation. Move to a feature request at MongoDB JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've recently added support for this in the MongoDB C++ driver legacy release, it will be in the upcoming release candidate for 1.0.0:

[JIRA ticket in CXX Project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-278)

[Commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/commit/06cb7d5c8a0895b0e9fac835ba9bd1d60b96dd30)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I've checked it works is to create a JSON string, then parse it with the fromjson() method:

```
std::string s = "{\"x\": {\"$in\": [ /^foo/, /^bar/ ] }";
BSON b = fromjson(s);
connection->query("col", b);
```

However, I wonder if using fromjson() method is too expensive (due to string parsing) compared with direct composition of BSON objects. Any insight on this, please?